# Is there a software to test HDD internal mechanicals?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I hear this sound in my internal WD HDD and I don't know if it's a regular sound. I hear it randomly, it's a low volume rotational sound (with a high pitch) like whatever rotates is rubbing or needs lubrication or something, it happens for a second or so and then stops (hard to describe, and record as well it's low).
Does any one know a software that could test the motor or the internal mechanical parts performance, so I can find out if there's anything wrong?

Comment: Probably read/write heads are scraping the disk surface. That's the source of the sound. And that means an increase in bad sectors if not corrected quickly.

Comment: I ran both dlg tests and they both passed, any suggestions that could help?

Comment: @willy "both dlg tests" ???

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Western Digital Data Lifeguard](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=606&sid=3&lang=en) tool and run the tests.  This will tell you if drive is OK or not.  Much more than just SMART diagnostic.

This tool has more advanced features and is used by WD tech to determine warranty issues.

Comment: There's the quick test which is a SMART self test, and the extended test which is a surface test for bad sectors. Nothing about performance I suppose. Would both be sufficient to test the drive's performance, and speed of the mechanical parts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Error-checking tool of Windows:
Randomly right click a partition in “My Computer” to select “Properties”=> Open “Tools” tab and hit “Check Now”.
If your drive problem is not serious, this checking tool always can automatically fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the windows tool doesn't give you enough detail, and vendor provided software is often at the other end of the spectrum (too technical).

I always found SpeedFan (windows) presents SMART* statistics in an easy to read table, offering a nice compromise between those two extremes

*Self-Monitoring Analysis and Reporting Technology, ie, error logs recorded by the hard drive itself.

http://www.almico.com/sfscreenshots.php